# How to use AudioContext to play multiple audio clips

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

What I am trying to do is play multiple audio clips in sequence using AudioContext so that the audio is smooth but I am doing something wrong. Most of the documents I've seen only show how to use a Synthesizer or play 1 audio. How would I go about creating this in plain javascript?

The idea is to:

1. Create AudioContext
2. Load the required audio as a buffer
3. Queue up the audio in a sequence
4. Let the user play/pause/stop the audio
5. Let the user control volume and speed

For example:

- Audio1 starts at 0 seconds and runs for 5 seconds
- Audio2 starts at 5 seconds and runs for 5 seconds
- Audio3 starts at 20 seconds and runs for 10 seconds

```html
<button id="AudioLoad">Load</button>
<button id="AudioPlay">Play</button>
<button id="AudioPause">Pause</button>
<button id="AudioStop">Stop</button>
<input id="AudioVolume" type="range" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="1.0" value="0.4">
<script>
const myPlayerLoad = (async () => {
  const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
  const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

  // load audio buffer from server
  const audioBuffer1 = await fetch('https://assets.mixkit.co/sfx/preview/mixkit-game-show-suspense-waiting-667.mp3').then(r => r.arrayBuffer());
  const audioBuffer2 = await fetch('https://assets.mixkit.co/sfx/preview/mixkit-retro-game-emergency-alarm-1000.mp3').then(r => r.arrayBuffer());
  const audioBuffer3 = await fetch('https://assets.mixkit.co/sfx/preview/mixkit-trumpet-fanfare-2293.mp3').then(r => r.arrayBuffer());

  // create audio context
  const audioContext1 = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer1);
  const audioContext2 = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer2);
  const audioContext3 = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer3);

  // create audio source
  const audioClip1 = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  audioClip1.buffer = audioContext1;
  audioClip1.connect(gainNode);

  const audioClip2 = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  audioClip2.buffer = audioContext2;
  audioClip2.connect(gainNode);

  const audioClip3 = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  audioClip3.buffer = audioContext3;
  audioClip3.connect(gainNode);

  // connect volume control
  gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  // play audio at time
  audioClip1.noteOn(0);
  audioClip2.noteOn(5);
  audioClip3.noteOn(20);

  // controls
  document.getElementById('AudioPlay').addEventListener('click',(clickEvent)=>{ /* code */ });
  document.getElementById('AudioPause').addEventListener('click',(clickEvent)=>{ /* code */ });
  document.getElementById('AudioStop').addEventListener('click',(clickEvent)=>{ /* code */ });
  document.getElementById('AudioVolume').addEventListener('change',(changeEvent)=>{ /* code */ });

});

document.getElementById('AudioLoad').addEventListener('click',(clickEvent)=>myPlayerLoad());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to play more than one music file, but you will have a better experience if you create a pre-loader that downloads the files and prepares them for use before the rest of the program runs.

Here's a link to one that I created (with help from a great guy!) to load my gaming assets  including sound files (which need a bit more prep than the others) [file loader](https://github.com/Fishbite/webAudio/blob/master/lib/assets.js)

I use it to load and prepare a number of file types. The `load()` method is what you use load the files. It creates a promise after which is fulfilled allows you to run the rest of your program. It's comprehensively documented throughout and you will see at the top of the file that **sound** files depend on an imported function `makeSound()` which you can find in the `lib` folder along with the `assets file` the `makeSound()` function does far more than you need, but you might find some interesting techniques in there. The book from which this was created along with its' author are attributed throughout.

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.